# Trying to create CNN using Theano and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-science, theano

I am trying to create CNN using theano and tensorflow. Defined layers are MLP, convolvemaxpool in different classes now I am trying to create CNN using these classes depending on the input provided by user. CNN should call theano or tensorflow classes depending on the user input. Now, Let's say theano and tensorflow both has classes MLP, convolvemaxpool implementing MLP, Convolution simultaneously. Now my problem is how to call the classes depending on the input? I don't want to use if else since adding more libraries means more if else statement for each class which I don't think is a right solution for now. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1. why you need to build CNN by two framework? 2. how to distinguish these two kinds of inputs

Comment: We want to run our models in more than one framework because we have already built our models using theano and now we want to port it to tensorflow but instead we thought why not abstract it out and get support to insert more than one framework.

Comment: input is provided by our internal users so we can fix the inputs to use. I think i am going to use importlib.import_module for importing a lib and pass the input to import_module function.

Comment: I'm also interesting that does there a way to do this without `if-else`? so just talk. if you have a `bool`, call `funcA` if it is `True` and call `funcB` if it is `False`, any way to do this whitout `if-else`?

Comment: Actually I am doing it without using if else now. I will add a small snippet here.

Comment: In File1:
filename: class1.py
`class A(object): 
    def __init__(self, a=10):
         self.a = a
         print self.a`
In file2:
filename: class2.py
`class A(object):
     def __init__(self, a=20):
          self.a = a
          print self.a`

in file3
`import importlib
class B(object):
     def __init__(self, inp):
          print importlib.import_module(inp)`
call B("class1").A() or B("class2").A()